# a:hover is not working as expected

Tags: html, css

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to implement  `a:hover` effect  as in attached image.But i have missed something it is not working .can you please correct me.

**HTML code:**

```
<ul class="short-by-list">
    <li class="right-mrgn">Make</li>
    <li>
    <a onclick="ajaxSearchLoad(5,49)" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img class="SortPosition" alt="ascending" src="../images/nav-arrow.png">
    </a>
    <div class="tooltip-text" style="display: none;">
    <img class="tooltip-arrow" alt="Arrow" src="../images/tooltip-arrow.png">
    Sort by Ascending
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
    </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.short-by-list {
    background: url("../images/short-bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 21px;
    margin: 0 6px 15px 0;
    padding: 0 6px 0 10px;
    width: 79px;
}
.short-by-list li {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 21px;
    position: relative;
}
.short-by-list li .tooltip-text {
    left: -38px;
}
.short-by-list li.last .tooltip-text {
    left: -40px;
}
.short-by-list li.right-mrgn {
    margin-right: 9px;
    min-width: 29px;
}
.short-by-list li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.short-by-list li:hover a, .short-by-list li.select a {
    background: url("../images/bg-hover.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.short-by-list li.select .tooltip-text {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: post your HTML  code also

Comment: Posting working sample demonstrating your problem would be even better: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: try setting height:auto for a.

Comment: Better create a simple fiddle. coz your code doesn't resemble your screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.short-by-list li`, try adding `height:21px;`

Answer (score 1):

I am suspecting that it is because the inner `<img>` element has been floated, therefore the height of the `<a>` element collapses. Try setting `overflow: hidden` for `<a>`.

If it all fails, set an explicit height for `<a>`.